# After migration index page still redirects to old url

Tags: redirect, migration

Hi,

I copied my entire site from myexample.com to myexample.org first by using Duplicator plugin but it didnt go well since it gave me encoding errors so I did it manually but now whenever I try to access the new URL it sends me back to the old one. It happens only with myexample.org or myexample.org/index.php since pages such as myexample.org/posts myexample.org/archive and so on work fine.

I tried by changing the database values in home and siteurl but no use. I even deleted the htaccess and still no use. Why is this happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that ```wp-config.php``` doesn't contain **old** database settings :)

Comment: It doesnt. I wouldnt be able to connect otherwise.